# How do I set up a website with mail address and password authentication in EnterpriseSearch as a data store?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vertex-ai-search

I want to set up a website with authentication by mail address and password in EnterpriseSearch as a data store. Is there a way to do this?
I have checked the documentation but can't find a way to do it.
If there is an alternative, please let me know.

https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/introduction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify, if you want to use Vertex AI Search (formerly Enterprise Search on Gen App Builder) to search websites that are behind a login/not accessible to the public internet, then that is not currently supported. You can try exporting the HTML from the relevant pages and creating an Unstructured data store from those HTML files instead.

However, if you were asking about storing usernames/passwords in Vertex AI Search, then that's not the intended use case for these data stores. They are only for storing data that is to be searched over.

You should use a database such as [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) or [PostgresQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) on [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql) to store usernames/passwords or use [Sign in with Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview).

I'd also recommend watching this YouTube video from Computerphile about password storage on websites.

[How NOT to Store Passwords! - Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q)

Comment: Thank you! 

I understand that it is not currently supported by Vertex AI Search to search for websites that are behind a login/not accessible to the general internet. 

Do you plan to support it in the future?

I will first try to put HTML on cloud storage!

Comment: Yes, that is a often requested feature. It's on the roadmap to be added.